# How to export RTSAllvouchers in excel

Tags: tally

Thanks for such a life changing report but I was wondering if we could do the same thing in excel instead of using calculator directly but it should update in real time when transaction made in tally. Please help as I am stuck in this matter for almost more than a year.
Thanks in advance

I anyhow need daybook transactions to be viewed in excel in real time